# Clean up url and make friendly

Tags: ruby

I have a url like this:

```
http:\/\/www.example.com\/embed\/J6ZzmqDMhi0?feature=oembed\
```

How do I convert that into to a normal url, like:

```
http://www.example.com/embed/J6ZzmqDMhi0?feature=oembed
```

Would this work?

```
simple_format(url)
```

What does sanitize do?

Comment: what do you mean by a normal url?

Comment: Are those literal backslashes? What do you want it to look like?

Comment: Updated it. See above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you want is to remove the backslashes?

```
url.delete("\\")
```

Comment: The trailing '\' at the end of the url seems to be commenting out the next line and not letting it work.

Comment: Please show the code. Update your question with a failing sample, so we can help.

Answer (score 0):

Given what you've shown (a URL with a bunch of superfluous backslashes), the obvious answer is `url.gsub('\\', '')`.